# Convert number of columns to rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a set of data that I need to transpose from columns to rows.
Any solutions to make it more efficient?

[image: Example data]

This is an example set of data. I need every four columns to be converted to rows.

Kindly advice. Thank you.

I have tried VBA and also macro. I can only transpose all columns in one row.

Comment: How many columns are you moving, and could you give an example screenshot of what you want the data to look like?

Comment: Hi, I apologize for not attaching sample data. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is messy, but it gets the job done.

Formula in `B2`:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,$G$1:$S$6,(COLUMN()-4)+(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)*4),0)
```

Copy the formula across to the `Q4` column and as far down as necessary.

[image]